# imageCache.clear() not working on ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, image, firebase, listview, flutter

`Image.network(url)` is showing the cached image(the image of the next item), in a ListView even though I have used `imageCache.clear()` in the build.

My code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 ....

 imageCache.clear();

 ....

 StreamBuilder( ....

   ListView.builder(
     scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
     itemCount: docList.length,
     itemBuilder: (context,index) =>

      ....

      Image.networl(url);

      ....

   ));
}
```

I have tried `imageCache.clear()` from `package:flutter/services.dart` as well as `package:flutter/painting.dart`.

The cache image is replaced when I go back and visit the page the second time.
Also, the image is loaded from Firebase storage.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5):

put a key in the image  `key: UniqueKey()` and use both  `imageCache.clear(); imageCache.clearLiveImages();`

Comment: Make sure you're using `imageCache` while accessing the object and not instantiating a new object (i.e `ImageCache()`). I thought that it is a singleton class and I was wrong.

Comment: Adding the `UniqueKey()` to the `Image` made the difference for me when clearing the image cache still didn't work.